# How to change quantity of columns in lightning-datable?

Tags: lightning-datatable

I have a dynimically change variable _viewItem:

```
@track _viewItem;
```

The object on the basis of which my columns will be created:

```
_columns = {
        courtesyId: {
        label: this.labels.courtesyId,
        fieldName: 'courtesyId',  
        order: 1,
        sortable: true, 
        sortBy: 'courtesyId',
        visible: true,
    },
     eventId: {
         label: this.labels.eventId,
         fieldName: 'eventId',  
         order: 2,
         sortable: true, 
         sortBy: 'eventId',
         visible: true
     },
     weeklyDate: {
         label: this.labels.weeklyDate,
         fieldName: 'weeklyDate',  
         order: 3,
         sortable: true, 
         sortBy: 'weeklyDate',
         visible: this._viewItem == 'Master' ? true : false,
     },
```

Getter which passes the columns to lightning-datatable if visible === true:

```
    get columns() {
        return this._columns ? Object.values(this._columns).filter(column => column.visible) : [];
    }
```

And lightning-datatable:

```
 <template>
     <lightning-datatable
         key-field="id"
         data={preparedRows}
         columns={columns}
         onrowselection={getSelectedRows}
         onsort={updateColumnSorting}
         sorted-direction={sortedDirection}
         sorted-by={sortedBy}
     >
     </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

But I have a problem with it, when I changed my _viewItem, then nothing happens. Also
"visible: this._viewItem == 'Master' ? true : false" always return false, even this._viewItem === 'Master'. May be anyone know how to dynamically changed quantity of columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reactivity_fields reactivity is ignored since it doesn’t impact the rendered content

workaround:

```
getColumns(visible) {
    return {
        courtesyId: {
            label: 'courtesyId',
            fieldName: 'courtesyId',
            order: 1,
            sortable: true,
            sortBy: 'courtesyId',
            visible: true,
        },
        // ...
        weeklyDate: {
            label: 'weeklyDate',
            fieldName: 'weeklyDate',
            order: 3,
            sortable: true,
            sortBy: 'weeklyDate',
            visible: visible === 'Master'
        }
    }
}

_columns = this.getColumns();

get columns() {
    return this._columns ? Object.values(this._columns).filter(column => column.visible) : [];
}

inputChange(event){
    // Master is here => column will be shown
    this._columns = this.getColumns(event.target.value);
}
```

Thanks